# splice strings javascript that contain '>>'

Tags: javascript

I have a strings with '>>' inside

An example is ">>.H.23..H.2"

I want to change the 3rd character to a '>', I'm trying this using substrings :

```
let indexToChange = 2
let indexToChange = 2
let startStr = ">>.H.23..H.2"

let substr1 = startStr.substring(0,indexToChange)
let substr2 = startStr.substring(indexToChange + 1)
let replacementChar = '>'

console.error('substring 1 [' + substr1 + '] len ' +  substr1.length)
console.error('substring 2 [' + substr2 + '] len ' +  substr2.length)
var c = substr1.concat(replacementChar).concat(substr2)
console.error(c)
```

This give the following incorrect answer

```
substring 1 [>>] len 2
substring 2 [H.23..H.2] len 9
>H.23..H.2
```

I expected ">>>H.23..H.2", if I use any other charactor, say setting replacmentChar to 'Y' I get a correct output :

```
substring 1 [>>] len 2
substring 2 [H.23..H.2] len 9
>>YH.23..H.2
```

Is there some special meaning to ">>>" or have I made a mistake. I can use any other characters without an issue.

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked fine. It gave me output as `>>>H.23..H.2` which is the expected result I think. The only mistake you have done is to declare same variable `indexToChange ` twice using let. So just remove the first or second line of the code and it should work fine.

Comment: also maybe check out [`.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Comment: Thanks for trying this code, I've been using the on line compiler https://www.programiz.com/javascript/online-compiler/

Which gives the error, I didn't think of trying another. I've just tried it else where and my code works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This how you can do that.

```
<script>
  let startStr = ">>.H.23..H.2"
  // convert the string to an array
  let startStrArr = startStr.split('');
  // use splice to replace the third element - 
  startStrArr.splice(2, 1, ">");
  // convert back to string
  let finishedStr = startStrArr.join('');
</script>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, as I said above the error seems to be with the compiler/tool that I have been using.
Thanks for the code snippet

Comment: Ha, just tested in that online compiler.  In that compiler, console.log() seems to replace '>>>' with '>', so this statement at the end gets the correct output:  console.log('>>>>>>'+finishedStr);  LOL